# Copying rows from a range based on a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy only new rows in a range from sheet1 based on a variable and paste after the last row in sheet2

When the code below is executed all rows on sheet1 are copied to sheet2. I wonder if there is a way to copy only newly added rows to sheet1, For instance, I have 8 rows that meet the criteria, I run the code and all 8 are copied to sheet2. Next, I add two new rows to sheet 1 that meet the criteria. When I run the code, only two new rows are copied to sheet2. Also,  I will need the new rows to be pasted after the last row in sheet2.

```
    Sub CopyInfo()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Sheet1.Range("A3:C1000", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 4, "Applicable"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).Resize(,3).Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheet2.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: How would Excel know which rows are already copied and which aren't? You would need to flag the rows somehow with a status. Right now, your code is very efficient. Why not just copy everything? What does it matter? Keep it simple.

Comment: To ensure you only copy the new data each time you run your code, you need to clear your filter criteria "Applicable" in `Column D` each time you copy the data to `Sheet2`.

Comment: Will it be possible if you use pivot table ? Have the data in Sheet1 as the pivot table data source, put the pivot table in Sheet2, then in the pivot table, have column D (which has the possibility that the row value is "applicable") as the page field. No macro needed, but then you need to refresh the pivot table after you add/correct data in Sheet1.